# How do I do rounded corners in CSS in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, border, chromium

Basically I am trying to work out how I do rounded corners on a DIV in CSS that will render in google chrome

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Google Chrome (and Safari) work with the following CSS 3 prefixes

```
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
```

for all corners at 10px

```
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 8px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
```

for the top left corner and bottom left at 8px

For Firefox you can use:

```
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
```

for all the corners and

```
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 8px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 8px;
```

for the top left corner and bottom left

Comment: @Spasm i think you have it but just to be clear border-radius is the CSS 3 class.  webkit prefix is specifically for Chrome and other webkit browsers.

Comment: @dove - since Spasm didn't mention `border-radius` without the prefixes, are you just wanting to point out that some day there will be a browser other than Opera that supports this style rule without the prefix?

Comment: @Anthony: Hopefully Webkit and Mozilla browsers will some day drop the prefix, and just convert to the default, like they're supposed to. And if you already have `border-radius` in there, then you won't have to go in and change your code...

Comment: @Dove - I agree we should not be going down the road where there are different prefixes for the same effect on a style rule. I was merely just trying to answer the question and to illustrate there are different methods. Your comments indeed are correct, thx for clarifying for readers

Answer (score 21):

To cover both Chrome, FF and any browser that supports CSS 3:

```
{-webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px;}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's future-useful to code your css like this:

```
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
```

That way, when IE9/IE10 comes out your code will also work there as well :D

Answer (score 3):

Given that all browsers now support border-radius without prefixes; see: http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius the correct syntax to use today is simply:

```
border-radius: 5px;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes but the only problem with this is that you are actually throwing css errors because of IE being jacked and Microshaft not wanting to do anything about it, the fix that i use is js based but I imagine most people know all about that. But, the reason I use it is because it always works for me and on all the major browsers. Here you go.

```
var obj= document.getElementById('divName');
var browserName=navigator.appName; 
var browserVer=parseInt(navigator.appVersion); 
//alert(browserName);
if ((browserName=="Microsoft Internet Explorer")) {
obj.style.borderRadius = "15px";
}else {
    obj.style.MozBorderRadius = "15px";
    obj.style.WebkitBorderRadius= "15px";

}
```